# Is accessing the camera feed on ios possible with a javascript only approach? In regards to object character recognition in realtime with camera feed

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, camera, ocr

I am trying to make an iphone app with react native that will do image recognition processing on a frame by frame basis of just 2d text.  I am aware that this is definitely possible in something like Swift, but are there any tricks with javascript that gives me access to the camera along with the data from the camera feed to do calculations?

I am thinking about using:
https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

and doing something along the lines of: setInterval(captureImage, 1000)

where captureImage is a function feeding image data in real time from the camera feed to a object recognition library.

Is the above a "standard" approach?  I'm new to the concept of OCR and I would love to find more about a javascript solution.  I'm wondering how the react-native-camera library is able to have a barcode reading feature which is a lot like something I want to do just for text on a page, unless a solution like that is NOT possible with javascript only... Anything would help at this point and thank you for reading!

Comment: CameraRoll is very limited. There is a framework on github called React Native PhotosFramework that is pretty good. The camera is great but dealing with an interval like that you will have to deal with memory if you are saving the images at all when in Native it is much easier. I am not sure but I think the Camera saves images automatically. Not sure there. I have similar requirements and as of now I have 5 Native components/frameworks and expect 1 more. The trade off is not bad as we could get someone to fill in the holes on Android if they decide to launch there.